# jQuery click not working on the <i> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZkG2/1/) that doesn't seem to work. It might be because of the `<i>` tag, if so please tell me why. I am trying to use `font-awesome` icons and if clicked I want to call certain things in jQuery.

jquery:

```
$('#video-mirrors-handler').click(function() {
    // var class = $('ul.video-mirrors').attr('class');
    alert('test');
    alert(class);
});
```

and html:

```
<div class="video-player-overlay"><i id="video-mirrors-handler">test</i>

</div>
<ul class="video-mirrors">
    <li>hey</li>
    <li>bye</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please put the relevant parts of the code *in* your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You using keyword class as variable which is not allowed, else your code is perfect:

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/rZkG2/2/)

```
$('#video-mirrors-handler').click(function() {
    var myClass = $('ul.video-mirrors').attr('class');
    alert('test');
    alert(myClass);
});
```

Comment: Well that was an annoyance. Couldn't figure out what was wrong after searching for so long and had to succumb to the temptation of asking on stackoverflow. Sorry for the trouble, and thanks for pointing that out :)